# How to grab the lines AFTER a matched line in python

Tags: python, text, file-io

I am an amateur using Python on and off for some time now. Sorry if this is a silly question, but I was wondering if anyone knew an easy way to grab a bunch of lines if the format in the input file is like this:

"
Heading 1

Line 1

Line 2

Line 3

Heading 2

Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
"

I won't know how many lines are after each heading, but I want to grab them all. All I know is the name, or a regular expression pattern for the heading.

The only way I know to read a file is the "for line in file:" way, but I don't know how to grab the lines AFTER the line I'm currently on. Hope this makes sense, and thanks for the help!

*Thanks for all the responses! I have tried to implement some of the solutions, but my problem is that not all the headings are the same name, and I'm not sure how to work around it. I need a different regular expression for each... any suggestions?***

Comment: In response to your edit: you need to have a way of identifying which lines are headers. Can you provide some actual examples?

Comment: Sure, here are some regular expressions I'm using to identify headers, delimited by //:'[0-9]+ common elements:' // '[0-9]+ models with [0-9] elements:' // 'Model model_[0-9]el_[0-9]'

Comment: Don't confuse this problem (header and details) with a second -- and only partially-related problem.  Don't update this to add confusion.  First: Search SO for regular expression help.  Second: Search Python tutorials for regular expression help.  Third: after trying code that doesn't work, create a **new** question just focused on your regular expression problem.  With code.  That doesn't work.

Comment: I am not having trouble with regex - they are working fine. My problem is simply that your solution assumes that each heading starts with "Heading," whereas in actuality the headings are entirely different from each other. Is there a way to easily modify your solution for this situation? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generator Functions

```
def group_by_heading( some_source ):
    buffer= []
    for line in some_source:
        if line.startswith( "Heading" ):
            if buffer: yield buffer
            buffer= [ line ]
        else:
            buffer.append( line )
    yield buffer

with open( "some_file", "r" ) as source:
    for heading_and_lines in group_by_heading( source ):
        heading= heading_and_lines[0]
        lines= heading_and_lines[1:]
        # process away.
```

Comment: +1, but I think you mean `buffer= [ line ]` instead of `buffer= [ heading ]`.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great solution (had to do some reading up on generator functions).

Comment: @toofly:  If you accept S.Lott's answer, you will both gain reputation points.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a variable to mark where which heading you are currently tracking, and if it is set, grab every line until you find another heading:

```
data = {}
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line: continue

    if line.startswith('Heading '):
        if line not in data: data[line] = []
        heading = line
        continue

    data[heading].append(line)
```

Here's a http://codepad.org snippet that shows how it works: http://codepad.org/KA8zGS9E

**Edit**: If you don't care about the actual heading values and just want a list at the end, you can use this:

```
data = []
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line: continue

    if line.startswith('Heading '):
        continue

    data.append(line)
```

Basically, you don't really need to track a variable for the heading, instead you can just filter out all lines that match the Heading pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Other than a generator, I think we can create a dict where the key is "Heading" and the value is one list to save the lines. Here is the code

```
odd_map = {}
odd_list = []
with open(file, 'r') as myFile:
    lines = myFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "Heading" in line:
            odd_list = []
            odd_map[line.strip()] = odd_list
        else:    
            odd_list.append(line.strip())

for company, odds in odd_map.items():
    print(company)
    for odd in odds:
        print(odd)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know Python, but here's a bit of pseudocode.

int header_found=0;

[start where loop where you're looping through lines of file]

if(header_found==1)
    [grab line];
    header_found=0;

if(line=~/[regexp for header]/)
    header_found=1;

The idea is to have a variable that keeps track of whether or not you've found a header, and if you have, to grab the next line.