# How to grab all lines after a match in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and I saw a post here: 
[How to grab the lines AFTER a matched line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595197/how-to-grab-the-lines-after-a-matched-line-in-python)

I have a file that has data in the following format:
    DEFINE JOBPARM ID=(ns_ppprtg_notify,nj_pprtd028_notify,0028)

```
SUBFILE='/sybods/prod/ca_scripts/ca_notify.ksh' SUBUSER=pbods SUBPASS=*PASSWORD*
```

I am attempting to extract each parameter so that I can construct the full command line.

Here is what I have so far:

```
with open(myExtract) as Extract:
    for line in Extract:

        currentLine = line.strip("\n").strip()

        if currentLine.startswith("DEFINE JOBPARM ID=") or \
                currentLine.contains("PARM")):

            logger.info("Job Parameter line found")

            if "DEFINE JOBPARM ID=" in currentLine:
                tJobParmString = currentLine.partition("DEFINE JOBPARM ID=")[2].parition("SUBFILE")[0].strip()
                tSubFileString = currentLine.partition("SUBFILE")[2].partition("SUBUSER")[0].strip()
                tSubUserString = currentLine.partition("SUBUSER")[2].partition("SUBPASS")[0].strip()

                if re.match(" PARM", currentLine, flags=0):
                    logger.info("PARM line found")
```

This is where I am stuck...
I don't know for sure that there will be 2 PARM lines or 10. They all start with " PARM" and have numbers. How do I extract the values for PARM1, PARM2, PARM3 etc? 
Each of the PARM lines (PARM1, PARM2) always starts on a new line.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: DEFINE JOBPARM ID=(ns_ppprtg_notify,nj_pprtd028_notify,0028) SUBFILE='/sybods/prod/ca_scripts/ca_notify.ksh' SUBUSER=pbods SUBPASS=*PASSWORD*
 PARM1='EPRTYADR'
 PARM2='1\>\>${LOG_DIR}/${JOBSET}.${JOBNAME}.${BUSDATE}'
 PARM3='2\>&1'

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your input file?

Comment: DEFINE JOBPARM ID=(ns_ppprtg_notify,nj_pprtd028_notify,0028) SUBFILE='/sybods/prod/ca_scripts/ca_notify.ksh' SUBUSER=pbods SUBPASS=*PASSWORD*
 PARM1='EPRTYADR'
 PARM2='1\>\>${LOG_DIR}/${JOBSET}.${JOBNAME}.${BUSDATE}'
 PARM3='2\>&1'

Comment: The DEFINE JOBPARM ID line, PARM1, PARM2 and PARM3 are all on separate lines

Comment: So, you want to assign all the strings after the `=` for lines beginning with PARM to some sort of data structure and then do stuff with that data?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am trying to do...once I am able to extract the strings after the = then I have another method to which they will be passed and massaged for conversion

Comment: And this is python 2.7 or 3?

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go mate. Here's my attempt at your problem. I've given you three options in the data structure layout; `outDict` which maps the PARMs to the strings; `outListOfTups` which gives you the same data as a list of tuples; and `outList` which assumes you're not interested in the PARMS:

```
f = open("data.txt", 'r')
lines = f.read().splitlines()
outDict = {}
outListOfTups = []
outList = []

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('PARM'):
        splitPoint = line.find("'")
        name = line[:splitPoint-1]
        string = line[splitPoint:].replace("'", "")
        outDict[name] = string #if you want to work with dict
        outListOfTups.append((name, string)) #if you want lists
        outList.append(string)

print(outDict)
print(outList)
print(outListOfTups)
```

Let me know if I've misunderstood where you're coming from - this works for me on the input sample given.

Comment: I think I found one solution too...let me know if this is good coding practice or not...

Answer (score 0):

```
if("DEFINE JOBPARM ID=" in currentLine):
                tJobParmString=currentLine.partition("DEFINE JOBPARM ID=")[2].partition("SUBFILE")[0].strip()
                tSubFileString=currentLine.partition("SUBFILE")[2].partition("SUBUSER")[0].strip()
                tSubUserString=currentLine.partition("SUBUSER")[2].partition("SUBPASS")[0].strip()
            if(re.match("PARM",currentLine,flags=0)):
                logger.info("PARM line found")
                tParmString=currentLine.partition("=")[2].strip()
                logger.info(tParmString)
                if(not "PARM" in currentLine):
                    continue
```