# Select specific column in python for scattered data

Tags: python, regex

I have a space seprated file, from which I have to get the data of a particular column. My file looks like below:

```
chr1.trna124 (75052562-75052633)        Length: 72 bp
Type: His       Anticodon: ATG at 33-35 (75052594-75052596)     Score: 35.2
HMM Sc=29.40    Sec struct Sc=5.80
     *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |
Seq: TGGGGTATAGCTCCATGGTAGAGCGCATGCCTATGAAGCGTGAGGtCCTGGGTTTGATCCCCAGAACCACAA
Str: >>>>>>>..>>>>.......<<<<.>>>>>.......<<<<<.....>>>>>.......<<<<<<<<<<<<.

chr1.trna131 (78297795-78297866)        Length: 72 bp
Type: Pro       Anticodon: AGG at 33-35 (78297827-78297829)     Score: 39.1
HMM Sc=24.30    Sec struct Sc=14.80
     *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |
Seq: GGCTTGTTGGTCTAGGGGTATGATTCTCACTTAGGGTGTGAGAGGtCCTGGGTTCAAATCTTGGACGAGTCC
Str: >>>>>>>..>>>>.......<<<<.>>>>>.......<<<<<.....>>>>>.......<<<<<<<<<<<<.
```

From above I want to extract ID ie "chr1.trna124" column and from second line from Anticodon: ATG at 33-35 only 33-35 till end of file. 
What could be the best way?
I am trying to merge the lines in one line where pattern matches "chr" till next "chr" and then fetch the columns. I tried via [How to grab the lines AFTER a matched line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595197/how-to-grab-the-lines-after-a-matched-line-in-python) But I am unable to do this even. Is there any better way?
Are there different way of doing this in python 2X and 3X?

Comment: Show your code please. Also, I don't think this fundamentally has anything to do with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use re.findall(r"(?ms) see below"):
 (1) "^[\w.]+\s\((\d+-\d+)\)" matches the ID, from start of a line;
 (3) "(Anticodon:.+?)$" matches from "Anticodon" until the line end,
 '^' and '$' match not only the start/end of the string but each line start/end, too, according the 'm' in (?ms);
 (2) ".+?" matches anything from the end of the ID to the "Anticodon", and . matches new line, too, according to 's' in "(?ms)".
 You can assemble the expression:-)
```